# Where clause on list property

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have two classes :

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }

    public string ProductColor { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a clause where on property `Product` (`Product.ProductColor == ""`) I do :

```
c.Where(x => x.Product.????? == "11").Select(x => x).ToList();
```

How do this ?

Comment: all customer who have a specific ProductColor for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to find customers, that have a product with Number 11. If so, you can use function `Any`:

```
var result = c
    .Where(x => x.Product.Any(p => p.ProductNumber == "11"))
    .ToList();
```

The code filters only those customers, that have at least one product that satisfies condition `ProductNumber == "11"`

Or if you want to find customers that have specific color then use different expression:

```
var result = c
    .Where(x => x.Product.Any(p => p.ProductColor == "Color"))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Product` (which *really* should be named `Products`) is also a collection, you'd have to drill down into that collection.  For example, if you want all `Customer`s from a list of customers where *any* product color is `"11"`, it might looks like this:

```
customers.Where(c => c.Product.Any(p => p.ProductColor == "11"))
```